# Flutter Web PWA

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I created a project in Flutter Web and uploaded the files to "Github Pages". I accessed the Url from a Smartphone (Android) and for some reason the App Install Box on the Android Device is not displayed.

Do I need to configure something in the Project?

Comment: it should come automatically, nothing to configure

Comment: can you provide url?

Comment: I created a new project with the Intellij IDE and marked: Android, iOS, Web, Windows. I compiled: "flutter build web" and put it on Github Pages and it didn't work. I'm using Flutter 2.10.5 and Dart 2.16.2

Comment: you can use canvaskit render and then publish it may be it will fix your issue.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release` link https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers

Comment: Must be something I'm doing wrong when uploading to "Github Pages". Thanks Ruchit